# Using a macro to copy a worksheet from another workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, macros

Here is my delima..

1. i am a noob with macros and am learning by necessity
2. this forum has been a great help but im still ignorant on a lot of scripting.

This is what i am trying to accomplish...
I have 1 folder (" Monthly reports") which contains
     "Monthly report.xlxs",
     "Feb_01_2017_Daily report.xls",
     "Feb_02_2017_Daily report.xls",
     "Feb_03_2017_Daily report.xls",  ect....

Each of the daily reports have multiple worksheets in them

What i would like to do is copy only the first sheet from each daily report and 
paste them into the Monthly report as their own worksheet with each worksheet labeled as "Day 1", "Day 2", "Day 3", respectavely

The monthly workbook is set up as
Sheet 1 -- is my worksheet compiling the data from the daily reports.
Sheet 2 -- is reserved for Day 1 data
Sheet 3 -- is reserved for Day 2 data
Sheet 4 -- is reserved for Day 3 date
all the way thru sheet 32 for day 31 data.

All i need to is to import worksheet 1 from the "Feb_01_2017_Daily report.xls" into sheet 2 of "Monthly report.xlxs"
Then import worksheet 1 from the "Feb_02_2017_Daily report.xls" into sheet 3 of "Monthly report.xlxs"
Then import worksheet 1 from the "Feb_03_2017_Daily report.xls" into sheet 4 of "Monthly report.xlxs"
all the way thru for 31 days.

I do not want to copy any of the other sheets in the Daily reports -- only sheet 1

My sheet 1 of the Monthly workbook filters it for the approptiate says ( this part works fine )

---

Sorry, I should have been  more specific
here is what i am using right now...

```
Sub CopyWorkbook()

Debug.Print "Started "
'  dimensions variables as type
Dim directory As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet
Debug.Print " completed 
' Turns off screen updating and display alrets
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Debug.Print " Turns off screen updating"

' Initialsizes the variable directory
fileName = "C:\Users\U486474\Documents\00 Monthly from xls\Daily Adjusted Files\DailyReport__2017-01-28_00-00__2017-01-29_00-00  Copy Test .xlsx"       ' actual file to be copied
Debug.Print " Sets file to be copied"

Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)      ' opens the Excel file
Debug.Print " Opens workbook of file to be copied"

Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets("Daily Report").Copy _
    after:=Workbooks("Monthly Adjusted Reports    Copy macro test.xlsm").Worksheets("Day 1")
Debug.Print " Copies files into existing workbook "

Workbooks(fileName).Close       ' closes the worksheet
Debug.Print " Closes workbook "
' Turn on screen updating and displaying alerts again
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


End Sub
```

I can not figure out why it is not copying the file.

it makes it to opening up the file but wont copy it. 
The script is for only 1 file right now  i will create the loop for the entire month once i get 1 day working

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If you step through your code with `F8`, does it skip the `.Copy` line? Also just double check the spacing in your worksheet names, it may be off (or was just an error when pasting here).  Do you get any errors? If so, what error where?

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it
I had to treat the copy and paste functions seperately

---

Public Sub CopyWorkbook()

Debug.Print " Started copy to worksheet -- once per worksheet"
             '  dimensions variables as type
Dim SourceFileName As String  ' sets the file path of the Folder

Dim DestFileName As String
Dim Range As Range
Dim SourceFile As Workbook  ' Sets tth Source File Folder
Dim DestFile As Workbook  ' Sets the destination Folder file

```
        ' Initialsizes the variable directory
```

SourceFileName = FiletoCopy
' Full Path for actual file to be copied
                Debug.Print " Sets file to be copied    " & SourceFileName

Set SourceFile = Workbooks.Open(SourceFileName)       ' opens the Excel file

```
             ' copies  the worksheet
```

SourceFile.Sheets("Daily Report").Range("A1:Z100").Copy  '  Copies cells from source worksheet

SourceFile.Close SaveChanges:=False ' Close the Excel file

```
    ' Pastes copied file into worksheet
    Debug.Print " Daysloop = " & DaysLoop
Dim PasteDay As String
PasteDay = "Day " & DaysLoop
PasteDay = WorksheetFunction.Text(DaysLoop, "00")
```

ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Day " & DaysLoop).Range("A1") ' Worksheet to paste onto

Debug.Print " FInished copy to worksheet -- once per worksheet"

End Sub

---

It may be a little clunky  but it works well with the loop i made to adjust for  number of days.

I do have a question though. ????

i had to use the entire path in the folder to copy from the worksheets.
They are located in a subfolder of where the excel worksheet is.

is there a way to use a shortened path in case the folder gets moved ?
All the references i can find online show the full path.